# "'toggleRow' is not defined" in javascript. My function is not found or being 'defined' as the error message sais

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function called "toggleRow" but when I am runing the application it seems like the function is not found when calling on it in my  tag. What the function is supposed to do is to expand and collapse a row in a table whenever I click on that specific row. In the example below I have only showed one of the rows.

I have tried to Writing the function and the Calling-on-the-function part a few times now but I Think I am missing something...

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<body>
<table>
    <tr onclick="toggleRow('hidden_row1')"><td>Ankit</td><td>25</td><td>60000</td><td>Com

    puter Programmer</td></tr>
          <tr id="hidden_row1" class="hidden_row">
            <td colspan=4>Ankit is 25 years old and he is a programmer</td>
          </tr>

</table>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      function toggleRow(row)
      {
        $("#" + row).toggle();
      }
    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

declare your JavaScript code at the end of your HTML file just before finishing your body

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Demo</title>
<meta name="author" content="Santhosh Thottingal">
<!-- Libs -->
</head>

<body>
<table>
    <tr onclick="toggleRow('hidden_row1')"><td>Ankit</td><td>25</td><td>60000</td><td>Com

    puter Programmer</td></tr>
          <tr id="hidden_row1" class="hidden_row">
            <td colspan=4>Ankit is 25 years old and he is a programmer</td>
          </tr>

</table>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      function toggleRow(row)
      {
        $("#" + row).toggle();
      }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the anwser. I can see that it works in the code snippet. I will give it a vote up but I still get the same error message (' 'toggleRow' is not defined')

Comment: haven't you declare it after your code ?? try executing from browser console. toggleRow' is not defined that means your JavaScript code executing before your HTML got render. Just put your JavaScript right before the end of your body tag

Comment: I have updated the code in my question so you can see what I mean

Comment: Thank you, I have in the question now

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: This code is working in my server please check my answer again I have updated it